# Some error on my code that I cant figure it out

Tags: minizinc

I used minizinc to program a shift planning code listed below. However , there's an error occurred with the error message : MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `forall(array[int] of var int)''

I would like to seed your help to figure out the reason. Many thanks

```
include "globals.mzn";
include "regular.mzn";
int: No_Shift = 7 ;
int: Hour = 24 ;
int: Cap = 30 ;

array[1..No_Shift , 1..Hour] of int: Shift_Available = [|1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 |0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
 |0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
 |0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
 |0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 |0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
 |0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0|];
 array[1..Hour] of int: Demand = [10,8,12,16,18,25,28,30,30,30,30,25,26,27,30,30,30,30,26,22,17,14,10,8];
 array[1..No_Shift] of var 0..30: Shift_Assigned;

 constraint forall(i in 1..No_Shift)(Shift_Assigned[i]>=0);
 constraint forall(i in 1..Hour)( 
                   sum(j in 1..No_Shift)
                          (Shift_Assigned[j]*Shift_Available[j,i])<=Cap);

 solve minimize forall(i in 1..Hour)(
                       sum(j in 1..No_Shift)
                          (Shift_Assigned[j]*Shift_Available[j,i])-Demand[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `forall` within the definition of the optimization goal. *AFAIK*, this is not supported.

Notice that you can iterate over both `i` and `j` from within `sum` as follows:

```
solve minimize sum(i in 1..Hour, j in 1..No_Shift)
  (Shift_Assigned[j] * Shift_Available[j,i] - Demand[i]);
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for your comment. The error did get fixed after using your recommendation. However, the output for the Shift_Assigned array was [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] , seems the code need to revise further. But thanks again!

Comment: @Carson Glad it helped. The question does not contain any details on the problem being solved, so I cannot help any further.